# how to get the results with less time for the following elastic search database structure in node js?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have a set of **filters data** like below format

```
filters = [  
{key : colour, values: [red,blue,green,yellow,........]},  
{key:website, values:[myntra, jabong, voonik,...........]},  
{key:shape,values:[fit, maxi,bodycon, skater...................]}  
,........................  
,........................]
```

my elastic search database structure is

```
{  
"_index": "products_data",  
"_type": "dresses",  
"_id": "1",  
"_score": 0,  
"_source": {  
"product_filter":{  
    "dress_shape": "sheath",  
    "pattern_type": "solid",  
    "discount_price": 1347,  
    "knit_or_woven": "knit",  
    "year": "2015",  
    "age_group": "adults-women",  
    "broad_category": "dress",  
    "fabric": "polyester",    
    "lining": "has a lining",  
    "surface_styling_or_features": "other",  
    "usage": "casual",  
    "sleeves_type": "sleeveless",  
    "brand": "deal jeans",  
    "website": "myntra",  
    "season": "fall",  
    "price": 2695,  
    "discount_percent": 50,  
    "product_line": "dresses",  
    "neck": "round neck",  
    "sleeve": "sleeveless",  
    "gender": "women",  
    "colour": "black",  
    "occasion": "casual",  
    "dress_length": "mini",  
    "display_name": "deal jeans black sheath dress",  
    "hemline": "curved",  
    "fabric_type": "lace or crochet"  
    }  
  }  
}
```

I need to find each filter count, like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frkND.png).
currently I am taking each filter and generating a elastic search query like below format and sending this query to elastic search count api for getting count.

```
{ "query": { "bool": { "filter":{ "term": { "product_filter.brand": "109f" } } } } }

output :  109f brand --> 2132
```

I have more data in each filter list. it takes around 6 seconds to give the 500 filters count.
 I tried the **multi search api(msearch api)**, but it is also taking the much time. my data size is 19787033681 bytes and it have 5 shards. 
Can anyone help me with this, with node js code...

Answer (score 0):

My advice for you is to reduce the number of shards from 5 to 1. Unless you have multiple machines working on the same data or desires to work with clusters, you should work with only one shard.

```
{
   "settings":{
       "number_of_shards":1,
       "number_of_replicas":0
   }
}
```

Working with multiple shards and replicas is efficient when having multiple servers/machines for insert/search/delete operations and redundancy purposes.

Comment: I have more data in elastic search database, if I make all into one shard, it will become too slow to serve the search requests. Reference :- [link]https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_basic_concepts.html#getting-started-shards-and-replicas